# Adding JavaScript Promise result to hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, promise

I have a form and JS promise functions on my homepage:

```
<form action="/run.php" method="POST" target="_blank" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="hiddeninput">
    <input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function go() {

    // get user input + other unrelated info
    .then(function(adding) {
            // calculations
            result = x;
        });

    document.getElementById('hiddeninput').value = "whatever"
}
</script>
```

`document.getElementById('hiddeninput').value = "whatever"` works (it's successfully POSTed with the rest of the form) if it's outside of the JavaScript Promise function.

However, it doesn't work when it's inside the JavaScript Promise function & from my understanding you can't return values from inside a JavaScript Promise to a higher scope, so is there any possible way I can access the `result` from the Promise function, so that I can set it equal to `document.getElementById('hiddeninput').value`?

Comment: just move the setter to `value` inside of the `then`.

Comment: I have tried that, as mentioned, it doesn't work then for some reason (although console logging works, just not POSTing)

Comment: your form is submitting, you'll have to block that first.

Comment: Any idea how I can do that, so it only submits after the Promise function has resolved?

Comment: you'll have to do it in a 2 step process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="/run.php" method="POST" target="_blank" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="hiddeninput">
    <input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function go(event) {
     var form = this;
     event.preventDefault();
    // get user input + other unrelated info
    .then(function(adding) {
            // calculations
            result = x;
            document.getElementById('hiddeninput').value = result;
           form.submit();
        });


}
</script>
```

Comment: the onsubmit will finish before the promise resolving

Comment: Is there no way to prevent that?

Comment: no the promise is asynchronous so the onsubmit will finish its execution before promise resloving, but onsubmit will not start until someone submit the form. is there a problem I don't understand why you wanna prevent that.

Comment: Because the Promise uses the `userinput` value to calculate the result. So `document.getElementById('hiddeninput').value = result` needs to be resolved before it's POSTed, otherwise I can't use the `hiddeninput` value.